# After show Modal Window jQuery validation plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a problem with [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).
I used ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework. The project has a lot of libraries and it's hard to understand the problem and find answer.
I have a form on which the section with fields. I used validation plugin for validate client-side fields. 
The section is collapsible and can to be open and closed. Inside section I have button for open modal window. Inside window I can to search data used Ajax. User can to add information manually, can add information used Ajax and fields can be empty.
The first task is to add validation for hidden fields. 
I added setDefault for validator inside $(document).ready:

```
 jQuery.validator.defaults.ignore = "";
```

When I added setting ignore for validator, everything work fine with hidden fields and open fields but after showing modal window validator plugin doesn't work. In FireBug I take error: TypeError: validator is undefined (twice). 
I open and close the modal window  (without Ajax search) and I take this error and validator doesn't work.

This is modal window code:

```
@using (modal.BeginBody()){
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6" id="search-entry-form">
        @using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form().HtmlAttributes(new { onsubmit = "return false" })))
        {
            @form.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model => model.EANCode).Label();
            @form.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model => model.Name).Label();
            @form.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model => model.InternationalName).Label();
            @Html.Bootstrap().Div(Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Text("Wyszukaj").Id("search-specific").Style(ButtonStyle.Success).
           ButtonBlock().PrependIcon("glyphicon glyphicon-search")).Class("col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-7");
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 top30" id="result-table"></div>}@using (modal.BeginFooter()){@Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("Zamknij").Data(new { dismiss = "modal" }).Style(ButtonStyle.Primary)}
```

I this file I added Bundels with Ajax code:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/specificNutSearch")
```

This is Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function pagination() {
    $('#result-table').each(Utils.Pagination);
}


function getData(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "GetSpecific",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            id: id
        },
    }).success(function (result) {
        if (result === null) return;
        for (var propName in result) {
            $(".panel [Name$='." + propName + "']").val(result[propName]);
        }
        clear();
    });
}

function clear() {
    $("#result-table").html("");
    $(".modal input").val("");
    $(".pager").remove();
}

function search() {
    var form = $("#search-entry-form :input").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#search-entry-form form').attr('action'),
        dataType: "html",
        method: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: form

    }).success(function (result) {
        $("#result-table").html(result);
        $(".select-specific").on("click", function () { getData($(this).data("specific")) });
        pagination();
    });
}

$("#search-specific").on("click", search);});
```

This is the field code which need validate:

```
     Html.Bootstrap().Div(
                                          Html.Bootstrap().Label("").LabelText("4.").Class("pull-left"),
                                          Html.Bootstrap().FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model => model.EAN).Label()).Class("col-lg-6")
```

In the **chhtml** view I added modal window on the bottom file:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="specificNutritionalPurposeSearch" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

It is ViewModel field:

```
 [Display(Name = "Kod EAN")]
    [RegularExpression("[0-9]{13}",ErrorMessage = "Kod EAN powinien zawierać 13 znaków")]
    public string EAN { get; set; }
```

**Also found a very strange thing:**
When I Comment out the all specificNutSearch (@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/specificNutSearch")) code, the plugin does not work.But when I comment out **@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/specificNutSearch"** line, plugin works.

What could be the problem? Maybe that's a problem of incompatibility of versions jQuery and Validator Plugin?

**EDIT:**

This is button code for open model window:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("Wyszukaj środek spożywczy").TriggerModal("specificNutritionalPurposeSearch").HtmlAttributes(new { href = Url.Action("SearchSpecificNutritionalPurpose") }).Style(ButtonStyle.Success).ButtonBlock().PrependIcon("glyphicon glyphicon-search")
```

This is ActionResult in Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchSpecificNutritionalPurpose()
    {
        var model = new SpecificNutritionalPurposeSearchViewModel();
        return PartialView("Modals/_SpecificNutritionalPurposeDictionarySearch", model);
    }
```

In action  model empty because modal window has button for searching data.

This is ActionResult for search button in modal window for searching data:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult SearchSpecificNutritionalPurpose(SpecificNutritionalPurposeSearchViewModel searchParameters)
    {
        var searchResult = _dictionaryRepository.FindSpecificNutritionalPurpose(searchParameters.EANCode, searchParameters.Name, searchParameters.InternationalName).Take(100).ToList();
        return PartialView("Modals/_SpecificNutritionalPurposeSearchResult", searchResult);
    }
```

Method **FindSpecificNutritionalPurpose** take data from dataBase (EF)

Comment: where is the code or and/orbutton which opens the modal? And what is the content of the specificNutSearch bundle? Is it some custom script of your own?

Comment: I added information. specificNutSearch = it is script in the top my post. (This is Ajax code)

Answer (score 0):

I think that when the specyficNutSearch script alters the DOM the validation handlers are getting removed.

My solution is to change clear method so it will refresh validation handlers:

```
function clear() {
    $("#result-table").html("");
    $(".modal input").val("");
    $(".pager").remove();

    //add this
    var $form = $("#search-entry-form form");
    $form.removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
}
```